# How to fix "No SIM" issue after flashing stock ROM?

Tags: sim-card

After using custom ROMs on my Motorola E4 Plus (Nicklaus) I figured out that there's no such custom stable ROM to install, so I recently flashed my device with stock ROM (Motorola Nicklaus MTK (XT1770)) but ended up with no sim support.

I tried to reset the networks but it didn't help me at all. I also reformatted the device and flashed with region specific stock ROMs too,
but that didn't help either. I flashed TWRP too. It showed OK while flashing using ADB, but recovery mode shows "No Command".

The problem is, currently I'm unable to use the stock ROM or to go back to those custom ROMs. Bootloader is unlocked. Every change has been executed properly as expected but not working on phone.

Comment: Please don't abuse quoting and font highlighting tools.

Comment: Does your device show a valid IMEI number, either in bootloader or by dialing *#06#? I am suspecting your EFS partition is corrupted and unless you have a backup is almost impossible for anyone but Motorola to restore.

Comment: @acejavelin no it isn't showing my IMEI number. And is there any way to fix this without backup?

Comment: There are some EFS partition backup files available on the net, you can try to use for recovery. I also had this problem some years ago on an old tablet. I never mad the mobile network back to live on that old tablet.

Comment: @Robert after researching on the internet I've found that the network issue ca be fixed on MTK devices if you'll be able to fix the IMEI. So going to flash the phone with the stock ROM and tweeking the **nvram** and **nvdata** entries.